# Android app has 5 second delay before loading

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I created a React Native project with `expo-cli`, starting from the "tabs" template (old sources of [app.json](https://github.com/expo/new-project-template/blob/master/app.json), [App.js](https://github.com/expo/new-project-template/blob/master/App.js)).
When I build the `.apk` en test it on my phone, it is slow to startup.
Upon clicking the app icon, it takes 5 seconds before it is loaded.

I demonstrate the problem in this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8KVy.jpg. What is happening in the video:

- "Geers Delivery" is the app with the problem.
- First time startup is fine: it show the splash screen immediately for +- 4 seconds.
- Second time starting the app: after clicking the app icon, nothing happens for 2 seconds. Then the "Say Ok Google" text disappears. 3 seconds after that, the app is shown.
- I open another app to show that my phone is not that slow in general.
- Switching to the app from the "good app" goes fast, no 5 sec delay here.

The delay is always exactly 5 seconds. Therefore, it might be a timeout of some operation?

Comment: same here. only for android. Did you found any solution to this?

Comment: No. I do remember that the bug was only on some phones, on other phones it worked without delay